# Display custom post type taxonomies as an archive page

Tags: php, wordpress

Hello I have a custom post type called `results`. I also created categories for that specific post type using a taxonomy. I'm not sure if I set it up correctly, but the code I have works so I'm sticking with it. If you see a better way or any errors please let me know.

I am able to create a custom post and set a category to it. Next I would like to create a categories page that will act like the regular archive.php but just for the category of the custom post types.

So say I have a custom post for `results` and I have its category set to `car accidents` I would like a way to display them all just like archive.php does for normal posts.

I tried going to a url like this but I get sent to a 404 page, even though I have an archive-results.php

`www.myurl.com/results/categories/car-accidents`

Here is the code I used to set up the custom post type and the taxonomy. Sorry If its long but I feel like its necessary to include everything.

```
// Create custom post type
function create_posttype() {
    register_post_type( 'Results',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Results' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Results' )
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'results'),
            'taxonomies'  => array( 'results', 'result-category' ),
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_posttype' );

//Create category for specific post type
function tr_create_my_taxonomy() {
    register_taxonomy(
        'results-categories',
        'results',
        array(
            'label' => __( 'Result Categories' ),
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'result-category' ),
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'has_archive' => true
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'tr_create_my_taxonomy' );
```

Am I missing something that is preventing this url from working?

`www.myurl.com/results/categories/car-accidents`

Thanks in advance

Comment: First of all to display that category you need to use taxonomy.php.. where all the categories of custom post type can be control and secondly use  flush_rewrite_rules(); while creating custom post type .. i think that is the cause of your url going to 404 page

Comment: for sure, i created taxonomy.php, now how do I view the page? that url still sends to 404

Comment: i tried your code it already worked mate just use flush_rewrite_rules(); after register_post_type() function

Comment: The url you're looking for based on your setup is: www.myurl.com/result-category/car-accidents because that's how you set up your rewrite. And it will be controlled by a file called taxonomy-results-categories.php, or fall back to taxonomy.php then to index.php.

Answer (score 1):

```
function namespace_add_custom_types( $query ) {
if( is_category() || is_tag() && empty( $query->query_vars['suppress_filters'] ) ) {
$query->set( 'post_type', array(
 'post', 'nav_menu_item', 'cmc-description'
    ));
  return $query;
}
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'namespace_add_custom_types' );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 // Create custom post type
function create_posttype() {
    register_post_type( 'Results',
array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'Results' ),
            'singular_name' => __( 'Results' )
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'results'),
        'taxonomies'  => array( 'results', 'result-category' ),
    )
);
flush_rewrite_rules();
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_posttype' );

//Create category for specific post type
function tr_create_my_taxonomy() {
register_taxonomy(
    'results-categories',
    'results',
    array(
        'label' => __( 'Result Categories' ),
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'result-category' ),
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'has_archive' => true
    )
);
}
add_action( 'init', 'tr_create_my_taxonomy' );
```

i Just made this changes can you please copy this to your code and see it runs well or not

Comment: so I should be able to go to this url?

Comment: /results/categories/car-accidents